# How to create a graph interface like server browser in Neo4J ?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, neo4j, neo4jclient

I'm starting with Neo4J and I've done installing it from my computer.
But I would like to show in my application the same graphical interface that it uses the "Server Browser".

It is a plugin? How to implement the same layout?

I'm already executed the movie example and already conected in the database with an tutorial with asp.net Mvc4 internet-based.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a example here: http://jexp.github.io/cy2neo 
and you can read more http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-data-visualization/

Also [graphgists](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/graphgist/blob/gh-pages/js/neod3-visualization.js) use a library that is similar to the one used in neo4j browser.

Comment: Hi Michael, 

How can I use your example with authentication?

Answer (score 2):

The [neo4j Browser implementation](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/tree/2.3/community/browser) is available as open source.

Comment: The Neo4j browser is an angular app in coffeescript that uses d3 for visualization.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but I need implement this in Asp.NET.
Node.js is not a option.

Comment: You don't need to use Node.js, the bit you'll most interested in is the D3 side of things, there are bucket loads of examples of using D3 on MVC, just have a perusal through your search engine of choice and you'll get there!